# Multiple validation rules on single element

Tags: jquery, forms

How can I call multiple functions on a single input element using Jquery?
(Not using any plugin)
For some reason mine isn't working. The check_email functions overrides the first one before it even executes.
Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#err-msg-email").hide();
var err_name = false;
var err_email = false;
 $("#email").focusout(function(){
    var input=$(this);
    var blank = input.val().replace(/ /g,'').length;
    var is_name=input.val();
    if(is_name&&blank > 3){input.removeClass("invalid-name");
    $("#err-msg-email").hide();
    input.addClass("valid-name");
}
    else{input.addClass("invalid-name");
    input.removeClass("valid-name");

$("#err-msg-email").html("* Email is required");
            $("#err-msg-email").show();
            err_email = true;   
}
    });

function check_email() {

        var pattern = /^[\w-.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
        if(pattern.test($("#email").val())) {
            $("#email").removeClass("invalid-name");
            $("#email").addClass("valid-name");
            $("#err-msg-email").hide();
        } else {
            $("#err-msg-email").html("* Invalid email");
            $("#err-msg-email").show();
            $("#email").removeClass("valid-name");
            $("#email").addClass("invalid-name");
            err_email = true;

        }

    }

$("#email").focusout(function() {

        check_email();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`focusOut` is an event emitted by the input box and you can bind only a function or attach a listener to that event. In other words when the event is emitted, you get a chance to respond to that event.

So in your code, you are basically over-ridding the binding itself. First you bind an anonymous function and later you override it with `check_email` function.

Effectively when the `focusout` event is emitted, there is only `check_email` function bound to be triggered. That is the reason you see no effect of your anonymous function (because it is not there at all.)

With this code it can't be concluded what you are actually trying to achieve. However if you want both the logic to work on focus out, you can put both the logic in a single function and bind that function to the `focusout` event.

I strongly recommend you to have a reading of [Javascript events binding.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp)

As mentioned earlier you can combine both your checks in one function. modify your check_email function as below:

```
function check_email() {

        var pattern = /^[\w-.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
        // checking for blank email here, we only move ahead if the email is not blank
        if($("#email").val() != '') {
          if(pattern.test($("#email").val())) {
            $("#email").removeClass("invalid-name");
            $("#email").addClass("valid-name");
            $("#err-msg-email").hide();
          } else {
            $("#err-msg-email").html("* Invalid email");
            $("#err-msg-email").show();
            $("#email").removeClass("valid-name");
            $("#email").addClass("invalid-name");
            err_email = true;

         }
      } else {
         // do whatever you want when the email is blank, e.g.
            $("#err-msg-email").html("*The email field is blank");
            $("#err-msg-email").show();
      }

    }
```

Comment: Well, I am working on a contact form, and trying to validate that the email field is not empty and in the right format. How can I bind the anonymous function together with the check_email function and execute them so that nothing is over-ridden ?